# c# logic approach to dispatch efficiency

Tags: c#, logic

Three taxis are queued and waiting for their next job in zone 1 
these taxi’s callsigns are 1,2, and 3 respectively;
The Taxis that arrived in zone 1 are first in queue.

Taxi 1 if first out taxi 2 is second out and Taxi 3 is third out.

However, Taxi 3 has a job that he has previously been assigned to and this job will be ready in 30 minutes but this job is in zone 2;

Taxi 3 decides to wait in zone 1 to see if a job is booked to take him to zone2 to link up with his job in zone 2 in 30 minutes.

Then one after another the central office take 3 jobs in zone 1. Once all the jobs are booked the taxi computer dispatches the jobs.
job1 goes to taxi 1 this job finishes in zone 2 
job2 goes to taxi 2 this job finishes in zone 25
job3 can't go to taxi3 because it finishes in zone 22 and would make him late for his job in zone 2 in 30 minutes.

It would make sense to send car3 on job1 and car1 on job3.

using c# programming how could i accomplish the most efficient way of dispatching the cars /jobs. So that Job 1 goes to Car 3 Job 2 goes to Car 2 and jJob 3 goes to Car 1.

```
ForEach (myJobObj job in JobsToBedispatched)
{
    ForEach (myTaxiObj taxi in taxisQued)
    {
    if(TaxiCanDoThisJob(job,taxi))
            {
                DispatchThisJobToThisTaxi(job,taxi)
            }
            else
            {
                MarkThisJobNoGoodForThisTaxi(job,taxi)
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried any thing on your own?

Comment: In general? You assign a job to one taxi, then one of the remaining jobs to the next and so on. Finally you get a count of "jobs that could be done". You do this for any possible combination of job/taxi (or until jobsdone equals taxicaount) and then choose the "best" one.
Though the problem might be "np-hard"?

Comment: I wish I had a higher IQ !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use external libraries (I assume some homework assignment) you should use the Combinatorics library (via NuGet). If not, do the combinatoric stuff yourself ;)

The idea:
You need all possible (non repeating) combinations of cars and zones to find the combination(s) that gets the most jobs done. Using `Variations` from the above lib, you already gives you this kind of two-dimensional assigment, because you get a value that has an index.
Please be aware that I'm not a C# guy, but prefer VB ...

```
private string[] jobs = { "Zone 2", "Zone 4", "Zone 45" };
    private string[] cars = {"Frank", "John", "Mary"};

    private void CheckJobs(){

        var k = new Combinatorics.Collections.Variations<string>(jobs.ToList(),3);
        foreach (var c in k)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if(IsPossible(cars[i],c[i])) count++;
                Console.Write("Driver {0} takes {1}   ", cars[i], c[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Jobs done = {0}", count);
        }
    }

    private Boolean IsPossible(string car, string job)
    {
        if (car == "Mary") {
            return (job == "Zone 2");
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckJobs();
    }
```

You can either use all combinations of cars OR jobs. This might be helpfull in cases where you have either more cars or jobs. If for example you have more cars than jobs, you create all variations of cars with a length equal to the number of jobs.
The only thing have to do else, is to simply select the Variations that have the highest number of jobs done (or whatever function you might want to use to measure "efficiency".